# Database Exception Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'configVersion' in 'field list'

Tags: database, error, entries-field

I get this Error when i want to save a Field. Also when i want to create a new field. I can hit the goback button and strangely the field gets still saved.[image]

I work local and have project config activated. At the moment i have no idea where to begin to eliminate that error.
I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After executing: `craft migrate/up --type=app` it works again.